# Calculate Probability of Getting Even Number of Heads with Biased and Fair Coins

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say that we have $5$ coins. Three of the coins are biased, with a $60$% chance of getting heads, and the other $2$ coins are normal, fair coins. What is the probability of getting an even number of heads when you flip all five coins.

My current understanding of the problem is that we have to calculate the probability of getting $0$ heads, getting $2$ heads, getting $4$ heads, and then adding those probabilities together.

I think I have the right solution to getting the probability of 0 heads, by multiplying $(\frac{1}{2})^2*(\frac{3}{5})^3$. I don't know how to get the probability for getting $2$ and $4$ heads however.

Comment: (1) Why do you think that is the probability for 0 heads? (2) How many ways can you get 2 heads? What are the probabilities of each? (3) same questions for 4 heads.

Comment: For $0$ heads, the second factor should be $(2/5)^3$.  For $2$ and $4$ heads, since $3$ of the coins are biased, the situation is more complicated than the simple [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
which focuses on $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$  For example, re $2$ heads, the number of heads from the biased coins could be either $0$, $1$, or $2$.  These $3$ situations have to be manually computed, **separately**.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is $\frac{1}{2}$ because it is entirely determined by the last (fair) coin.

Consider $p$ the probability of an even number of heads in your first $4$ tosses. Hence $1-p$ is the probability you have an odd number in the first $4$ tosses.

To get an even number in all five tosses you either have an even number in the first $4$ and then toss a tail, $p \cdot \frac{1}{2}$ *or* you have an odd number and then toss a head, $ (1-p) \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

Hence the probability of an even number of heads in the five tosses is just $p \cdot \frac{1}{2} + (1-p) \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} $

Comment: An elegant approach.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You are correct about your general approach: calculate the sum of the probabilities $Pr(H=0)+Pr(H=2)+Pr(H=4)$
$Pr(H=0)=(\frac{2}{5})^3(\frac{1}{2})^2$
$Pr(H=2)=3[(\frac{3}{5})^2(\frac{2}{5})(\frac{1}{2})^2]+(\frac{2}{5})^3(\frac{1}{2})^2 + 6[(\frac{3}{5})(\frac{2}{5})^2(\frac{1}{2})^2]$
$Pr(H=4)=2[(\frac{3}{5})^3(\frac{1}{2})^2]+2[(\frac{3}{5})^2(\frac{2}{5})(\frac{1}{2})^2]$

Edit: I can't comment because I am new and I need over 50 points to do so. But, I want to point out that the answer from Oskar is incorrect.  The flipping of the coins is not ordered as far as the problem states, so the last coin flipped does not have to be unbiased.  If the biased coin is flipped last, the logic breaks down.  Sorry to be a debby downer because I love elegant arguments too.  You can use that argument with modification by considering the average of all 5 coins holding the last position.  Recognize the p's won't cancel for biased coins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the order of coin tossing does not matter at all, hence one can decide that for him/herself and get the same result. would you really expect the answer to be different if we chose a different order of the coins? in your own answer you give you don't specify order so naturally it is an irrelevant factor we are able to decide for ourself to allow for an elegant approach .

Comment: i like your critical thinking and ability to look deeply at my solution! your answer is also completely correct so if you worked it out we would get the same thing :)

Comment: Thanks, Oskar.  I appreciate your approach, though it relies on the assumption that the last coin flipped is a fair coin.  If the last coin is biased, your results would not hold, and therefore are only correct for a subset of circumstances.  You'll notice that if you calculate the expressions I give, the answer is 0.464, which is just under 0.5.  Since the order does not matter, all last coin possibilities must be treated equally likely.  If you solve this given your notion of p for the first four coins, you get an expression: (4(3-p)+15)/50 and have to solve for p.

Comment: this is not actually true. the answer is most definitely $\frac{1}{2}$. We can at our own free will decide which coin is the last one. It is obviously true that the order in which you toss coins does NOT effect the sum being even or odd, why should it? Hence you can pick it for yourself